# Simple Excel if Statement with conditional

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Trying to check and see if two cells are both false, and use a 1 if BOTH cells satisfy the statement

```
=if(c2=false:d2=false,1, 0)
```

that's my statement, I'm trying to make sure both cells are false and then output a 1 if they both are, and a 0 if they aren't.

Comment: an error :), dunno what the deal is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `and()` function:

```
=if(and(c2=false,d2=false),1, 0)
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 46 seconds :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the cells contain either TRUE or FALSE and you want to check if they are the same then, simply:

```
=IF(C2=D2,1,0)
```

Would work in this instance.

Comment: He only wants the '1' if both cells are false.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right, was confused with the question.

Comment: Yeh, his first sentence doesn't quite jive with the last one.  I'll edit that.